# Posting a form with ajax - "The current request is not a multipart request"

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, spring

I have this simple form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/project/upload" target="myFrame"
enctype="multipart/form-data">


Please select a file to upload : <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
<input type="button" onclick="initSubmit()" value="upload" />
</form>             
<iframe name="myFrame" height=0 width=0></iframe>
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
```

here is my javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
    $("form#myForm").submit();
}

function initSubmit() {

$('form#myForm').submit(function () {
    $.post('/project/upload', $('form#myForm').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
            debugger;
         alert("Yeah!, i can get the call back!");
    });
    return false;
});
submitForm();
```

}

here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload( 
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException{
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
 // handle here
 }
return imageURL;
}
```

I'm 100% percent sure the ajax call is invalid for my controller

p.s I'm doing this for the callback function. i need to receive the imageURL back in the client and apparently forms callbacks are complicated.

p.s #2 - submitting the form regularly without the js addition, works, but then i cant get the callback context