# Form submit with result

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring

What are the methods for getting results from the server after submitting a form (i.e submitting a file for the server, and receiving a new URL)?

I've tried using the $.post() method but my controller doesn't recognizes the file i'm sending within the form

is there any other way?

EDIT -  my implementation 
[Posting a form with ajax - "The current request is not a multipart request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334772/posting-a-form-with-ajax-the-current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request)

Comment: can you post a code snippet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334772/posting-a-form-with-ajax-the-current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request